# Objective C: making point Larger through long press

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, core-graphics, paint

Is it possible to make a larger point in painting through long press? Because I want to make my line much bigger when I do the long press gesture and use that point to make a line in touches move. I hope this make sense, and this is my code.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event//upon moving
{

            UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
            previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
            previousPoint1 = currentTouch;
            currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];


            CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint2, previousPoint1); 
            CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentTouch, previousPoint1);


            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024, 768));
            [imgDraw.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextSetLineCap(context,kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, slider.value);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode);
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,red, green, blue, 1);
            CGContextBeginPath(context);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);//Computation
            CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);

            imgDraw.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
}
```

Now how do I insert my long press here?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to your view. This recognizer should then have a method associated with it that increases the radius of the point and then draws it, resetting the radius to some default starting value when the gesture ends.

Try something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(drawAndExpandPoint:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

Then, in the drawAndExpandPoint method, you can do something like (with an ivar called radius that has some default value):

```
-(void)drawAndExpandPoint:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{ 
    //Reset radius, if gesture ended
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        radius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
        return;
    }

    else if (radius <= MAX_RADIUS) {
        radius += RADIUS_INCREMENT;
        //You will have to write this method to draw the point
        [self drawAtPoint:[recognizer locationInView:self.view] withRadius:radius];
    }
}
```

This code may not be 100% what you've described, but I think it outlines the general strategy, which is to use a gesture recognizer--it makes things much easier.

Comment: is your code declared in UIView? what should I do if didn't use the drawinRec method to change self in your " [self drawAtPoint:[recognizer locationInView:self.view] withRadius:radius];"

Comment: No, I would declare this in the view controller that will handle the gesture. The method drawAtPoint:withRadius: is just an arbitrary method I made up. How are you doing your drawing?

Comment: I have an error in "self" for your arbitrary method.. I dunno what should i put there.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent
   *)event`

- Save a `UITouch` from the `touches` in an instance variable.

`- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches
   withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

- Check if the instance
  variable is set. If it is, calculate the difference in timestamps of the
  saved touch and the new touch. Use this difference to determine the line width then unset the instance variable.